# How to use javascript to pass a value to a textfield

Tags: javascript, html

i am developing a web page that accepts tags which i am supposed to submit afterwards to a database

presently i have been able to pass values to the textfield using this

```
<select name="one" onchange="if (this.value=='4'){
document.getElementById('cursor').value = 'one,two';

 }
  ;
">
   <option value="" selected="selected">Select...</option>
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">3</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
   <option value="5">5</option>
   <option value="6">6</option>
   <option value="7">7</option>
   <option value="other">Other</option>
   </select>

   <input name="tags" type="text" id="cursor">
```

now i am try to add more functionality to the textfield above

using the tag-it javascript lib

at this link :

```
   http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/
```

to create tags in my textfield

```
   <link href="css/jquery.tagit.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
   <link href="css/tagit.ui-zendesk.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script 
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" 
 type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery- 
   ui.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

    <!-- The real deal -->
    <script src="js/tag-it.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"> 
  </script>

   <script>
    $(function(){

        var sampleTags = 
   ['Wordpress','Joomla','Html','CSS','JavaScript/jQuery','JavaScript 
   Frameworks','Responsive Design','Testing/Debugging','Building and 
   Automation Tools/Web Performance','Command Line','Core Python','Web 
    frameworks','Object-relational mappers','Multi-process 
     architecture','Developing and using RESTful APIs','Building Python 
    application','Script writing','Systems administration'];


        //-------------------------------
        // Minimal
        //-------------------------------
        $('#myTags').tagit();

        //-------------------------------
        // Single field
        //-------------------------------
        $('#singleFieldTags').tagit({
            availableTags: sampleTags,
            // This will make Tag-it submit a single form value, as a 
                  comma-delimited field.
            singleField: true,
            singleFieldNode: $('#cursor')
        });
```

This is when i run into issues, the textfield value no longer gets updated as earlier did.

i am thinkin its because of the id which is been accessed by the tag it library.

because when i untag my id from the tag-it function

e.g here

```
     comma-delimited field.
            singleField: true,
            singleFieldNode: $('#cursor2')
  // changed my id here to cursor2, now the select menu function is workin 
     again
        });
```

how do i make this work, i need the tag-it function to work and i also need to be able to update the value of my textfield based on the select menu

thanks

Comment: now you have the ids 'curso', 'cusor' and 'cusor2' - plus 2 unused: '#singleFieldTags' and '#myTags'. What does the docs of "Tagit lib" state about those id's and their html elements?

Comment: first of all i have updated the tags from cusor to cursor where it matters, the cursor id is just an id to identify the textfield that needs to receive wat ever results any function assigned to it passes. e.g in terms of the select menu function it reurns a value back to the textfield